# Get line-numbers in which a certain word/text occurs

Tags: java, stream

**What I have:** I have a file which is read line by line. These lines are not counted within the file.

**What I want to do:** I want to count each line within ONE stream and return only the numbers in which a certain text occurs.

**What I have so far:**

```
public static Integer findLineNums(String word)
        throws IOException {

    final Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    final List<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(PATH)).collect(Collectors.toList());                 
    IntStream.rangeClosed(0, lines.size()-1).forEach(f -> map.put(lines.get(f), f+1));

    return map.get(word);
}
```

QUESTION: How can I do this using only a SINGLE stream ?

EDITED QUESTION: I'd like to do everything within the Stream, this includes also the accumulation into a list.

Best case scenario would be something like:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get(PATH)).superAwesomeStreamFuncs().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

EDIT: In my case I would only return a single Integer, but I would like to get something like a Integer List.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
int[] i = new int[]{0}; // trick to make it final
List<Integer> hits = <your stream>
  .map(s -> s.contains(word) ? ++i[0] : - ++i[0])
  .filter(n -> n > 0)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The main "trick" here is the use of an *array*, whose reference doesn't change (ie it's "effectively final", but which lets us mutate its (only) *element* as the counter, which is incremented in-line regardless. A quick filter throws out non-matches.

---

Some test code:

```
String word = "foo";
int[] i = new int[]{0};
List<Integer> hits = Stream.of("foo", "bar", "foobar")
.map(s -> s.contains(word) ? ++i[0] : - ++i[0])
.filter(n -> n > 0)
.collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(hits);
```

Output:

```
[1, 3]
```

Comment: Nice one, it seems it's a bit tricky to iterate within an array using stream-functions, I like your solution though.

Answer (score 3):

Following snippet would create a `List<Integer>` with the lines which contains the word

```
String word = "foo";
List<Integer> matchedLines = new ArrayList<>();
final List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("word_list.txt"));
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, lines.size() - 1).forEach(f -> {
    if (lines.get(f).contains(word)) {
        matchedLines.add(++f);
    }
});
System.out.println("matchedLines = " + matchedLines);
```

assuming the file `word_list.txt` as

```
foo
bar
baz
foobar
barfoo
```

the output is

```
matchedLines = [1, 4, 5]
```

**edit** To solve it with a single stream, create a custom `Consumer`

```
public class MatchingLines {

    static class MatchConsumer implements Consumer<String> {
        private int count = 0;
        private final List<Integer> matchedLines = new ArrayList<>();
        private final String word;

        MatchConsumer(String word) {
            this.word = word;
        }

        @Override
        public void accept(String line) {
            count++;
            if (line.contains(this.word)) {
                matchedLines.add(count);
            }
        }

        public List<Integer> getResult() {
            return matchedLines;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        MatchConsumer matchConsumer = new MatchConsumer("foo");
        Files.lines(Paths.get("word_list.txt")).forEach(matchConsumer);
        System.out.println("matchedLines = " + matchConsumer.getResult());
    }
}
```

Comment: This solves the List part, but what about doing everything in one stream ? How to iterate over elements in the middle of a stream ? EDIT: I also would like to do really everything within a stream, so in this case I also would like to accumulate the stream within an ArrayList.

Comment: @SklogW Have a look at the added example. I tought you wanted only the integers in one stream and not everything.

Answer (score 0):

This method returns line mapped by its number in file.

```
public static Map<String, Integer> findLineNums(Path path, String word) throws IOException {

        final Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        int lineNumber = 0;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b" + word + "\\b");

        try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) {
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                lineNumber++;
                if (pattern.matcher(line).find()) {
                    map.put(line, lineNumber);
                }
            }
        }
        for (String line : map.keySet()) {
            Integer lineIndex = map.get(line);
            System.out.printf("%d  %s\n", lineIndex, line);
        }
        return map;
    }
```

`BufferedReader` reads file line-by-line as does `Files.lines` stream.

Comment: This does not use Streams at all.